# How can I print straight to a thermal printer without dithering?

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, browser, printing

In a hardware store, we use a USB thermal printer (CITIZEN CT-S4000) at the desktop POS to print receipts on 104mm thermal roll. The billing software runs online, and generates a pdf receipt, which we print from the browser at the cashier's desktop box, running a Linux flavor based on Debian 10 (BunsenLabs). I chose to use Firefox because it is the default browser and because it automatically adjusts the length of the page so the printer cuts the receipt off correctly.

However, Firefox also *scales* the receipt **down** *incorrectly*:
[image: dithered receipt]
The text is dithered, and the printer does not use the whole page, even though the page width in the "configure printer" dialog is set to 104mm.

The driver is installed from the *.ppd on the manufacturer's website, via CUPS. If I print from a PDF document viewer (Evince), and tell it to scale to 120% (again in the "configure printer" dialog, the printout is clear, although I don't understand why the page shouldn't be able to be auto-scaled to the printout width:
[image: clear_receipt]

Is there a way to configure Firefox's built-in scaling/dithering so that I can hand-tune the printout to the actual page? The advantage to this would be that the cashier would only need to press the print button once.